# Hadoop which node will do split input data to multiple blocks?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-streaming

I am new to hadoop have few questions?

1. which node will do split input data to multiple blocks?
2. Find datanode based on shortpath . question is find shortpath between client vs datanode or datanode vs namenode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [client writes the blocks directly to the datanodes after communicating with the namenode for allocating block locations](https://data-flair.training/blogs/hadoop-hdfs-data-read-and-write-operations/#a_HDFS_Data_Write_Pipeline_Workflow)

I don't understand the second part. The namenode must be contacted for any client to know where a block is located. Without the namenode, you cannot retrieve the file content as a whole

Comment: Thanks for #1 question answer.

Comment: Thanks for #1 question answer.   form my understanding block reside in 3 data node ( replica ) what basis it will pick the node, for example, block A replicated in data node 1, 4, 5 .. so which node client will pick to process the data.. hope you can understand.

Comment: Doesn't matter. You shouldn't need to know. Rack locality is attempted to be optimized, though